# order results of linq query by multiple items

Tags: linq, entity-framework-5

using the following query

```
 Dim allEvents As New List(Of Events)
 Dim digits = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0".Split()
 Dim results = (From t In ctx.events
                           Where t.date = todaysdate.Date AndAlso
                           Not digits.Any(Function(d) (t.symbol.Contains(d)))
                           Order By t.time
                           Select New With {
                                  t.symbol,
                                  t.date, t.time,
                                  t.description,
                                  t.domestic_call_num,
                                  t.web_url})

             If results.Count > 0 Then
                For x As Integer = 0 To results.Count - 1
                    Dim newevent As New Events
                    With newevent
                        .CompanySymbol = results(x).symbol
                        .EventDate = results(x).date
                        .EventTime = Left(results(x).time.ToString(), 5)
                        .EventDescription = results(x).description
                        If results(x).domestic_call_num IsNot Nothing Then
                            .DialInNumber = results(x).domestic_call_num
                        Else
                            .DialInNumber = ""
                        End If
                        If results(x).web_url IsNot Nothing Then
                            .WebCastUrl = results(x).web_url
                        Else
                            .WebCastUrl = ""
                        End If
                    End With
                    allEvents.Add(newevent)
                Next
                Return allEvents
```

I get the results I want, but i'd like to further order them by description and time

I tried the following, which should have worked

```
 Dim results = (From t In ctx.events
                           Where t.date = todaysdate.Date AndAlso
                           Not digits.Any(Function(d) (t.symbol.Contains(d)))
                           Order By t.time
                           Group By t.description
                           Select New With {
                                  t.symbol,
                                  t.date, t.time,
                                  t.description,
                                  t.domestic_call_num,
                                  t.web_url})
```

I also tried ThenBy which the compiler didnt like. Any help on how to accomplish this would be appreciated. Essentially I want a sort order of time then description then symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using integrated syntax, you'd write this as:

```
Order By t.time, t.description
Select New With {
     ...
```

For details, see the [Query Expression Examples for ThenBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738627.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-3).

Comment: Reed, That is how I originally wrote it as it SHOULD work that way. With one Order By, t.time, i populate the events list  with no issues. Once i add a second one, t.description the code barfs on the first run through the add event. See the edit to my original post for more code

Comment: @dinotom The way I wrote it, above, should work perfectly fine.  It's a single "Order By" with `t.time, t.description` listed, separated by a comma.

Comment: I had removed the .ToList() to try to requery the original query. I have it all working now, ty

Answer (score 1):

You can try ordering your items at the end of the query like that :

```
 Dim results = (From t In ctx.events
                       Where t.date = todaysdate.Date AndAlso
                       Not digits.Any(Function(d) (t.symbol.Contains(d)))
                       Select New With {
                              t.symbol,
                              t.date, t.time,
                              t.description,
                              t.domestic_call_num,
                              t.web_url}).OrderBy(Function(r) r.time)
                                         .ThenBy(Function(r) r.description)
```

It's probably faster to do it in the query tho.

Comment: The speed will be identical - this should get translated into the same query on the server as my version (its just more difficult to read)

Comment: Oh, good to know, but I do agree that your answer is easier to read.